# Java: Function composition on stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to create some code like this:

```
this.getPendingDocuments()
    .forEach((this::documentProcessed).andThen(this::createAuditory));
```

So I mean, I need to apply two functions to the same element.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Compiler tells me:

> [Java] The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

[image]

Comment: Do these methods (documentProcessed and createAuditory) have a return value?

Comment: What do `documentProcessed` and `createAuditory` do? And why is the question about `Function` when we're clearly in the context of a `Consumer`? Can you perhaps clarify?

Comment: `Consumer` does have a `andThen` method. Does your code not work?

Comment: I've edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must *target* your method references to a functional interface type. In this case, `forEach` requires a `Consumer` instance:

```
Consumer<Document> processDocument = this::documentProcessed;
this.getPendingDocuments().forEach(processDocument.andThen(this::createAuditory));
```

The code above uses `Consumer.andThen` to chain consumers. Of course, both methods should accept a `Document` instance as an argument (or whatever the type of the elements of the `Iterable` returned by the `getPendingDocuments()` method is).

Answer (score 3):

You can write a lambda expression that executes both methods:

```
this.getPendingDocuments()
    .forEach(doc -> {
                        this.documentProcessed(doc);
                        this.createAuditory(doc);
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use forEach() you can add more functions inside... like this

```
this.getPendingDocuments()
.forEach( element -> {
     this.documentProcessed(element);
     this.createAuditory(element);
});
```